# Logging prepared sql query in groovy

Tags: java, sql, groovy

I need to logging my prepared sql-queries in groovy.

For avoid sql injection and have auto string-quotes(it's important) i used this design:

```
String name = "Bobby"
Integer status = 1    
def query = 'UPDATE my_tbl SET status=? WHERE name=?';
sql.execute (query, [status, name])
```

How i can get prepared sql-query with my params? 
May be other solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess what you want to do is log the query string with the `?` parameters replaced by their values? I don't know how to do this in the application logs, but your database probably has a query log that can show it.

If you use an overloaded version of `execute`, you can achieve something very close to what you're asking for

```
Map params [status: 1, name: "Bobby"    
def query = 'UPDATE my_tbl SET status=? WHERE name=?';
log.debug "query: $query, params: $params"
sql.execute(params, query)
```

Comment: Yes, you right understand me. 
But in application i can separate logs by files in one-call application scope. 
In DB logs a cant do this. I think one solution - create overloaded class. 

Thank you!